# Set image source from json config file for uwp

Tags: uwp

I've been setting the background image of my uwp app by using

```
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.webp" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

In MainPage.xaml. However, I want it to be so that the url is specified in my config.json file like this:

```
{
   "Programs":["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe","C:\\Users\\11031121\\Downloads\\TranslateText.py","https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.webp","false"]
}
```

And then I want to be able to put Programs[2] in the Image Source tag. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to use a JSON deserialiser to get a .NET object out of the JSON string. I'd recommend using a library like [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this. You can find very useful documentation of how to do exactly what you need over here - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Then, you'll want to use a data binding to be able to set the `ImageSource` property from C# code. For a quick guide on bindings, refer to Microsoft's [data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).

Hopefully this will put you in the right direction. Good luck!